# One to many relationship CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Core Data works great for the most part. When I click on name first VC (Items) and performSeque to the second VC (Costs), I can see the costsName and other data. But when I add second name in first VC I can see the same data as in first name.

I'm trying to make a one to many relationship.

I have 2 data models:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Items)
class Items: NSManagedObject {

   @NSManaged var count: NSNumber
   @NSManaged var name: String
   @NSManaged var cost: NSSet

}

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Costs)
class Costs: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var costsDate: NSDate
  @NSManaged var costsName: String
  @NSManaged var costsValue: NSNumber
  @NSManaged var account: Items

}
```

Here is `addAccount`'s (name of the first VC) save action:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let account = Items(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    account.name = cellOneNameTextField.text
    if cellTwoCountTextField.text.isEmpty {

    } else {

    account.count = (cellTwoCountTextField.text).toInt()!
    }
    // Saving data
    appDelegate.saveContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    var error:NSError? = nil

    var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Here is `addCost`'s save action:

```
    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // CoreData Access
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Costs", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let cost = Costs(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    cost.costsName = cellThreeNoteTextField.text
    cost.costsValue = (cellOnePriceTextField.text).toInt()!
    cost.costsDate = datePicker.date

    // Saving data
    appDelegate.saveContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Costs")
    var error:NSError? = nil

    var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

    for res in results {
        println(res)

    }
    delegate?.refreshTable()
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you do it somewhere, but your `Items` should attach a `Count` object to itself using your `cost` variable from your `Items`. Something like :

```
let account = Items(...)     
let cost = Cost(...)   
account.cost.addObject(cost)//and changing your var cost:NSSet into var cost:NSMutableSet
//then save Items
```

(I haven't tried the addObject but you understand the principle)